# What is the most efficient way to update an array with objects without re-rendering the entire DOM in RactiveJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ractivejs

If I have an array with objects in them.

```
var tableAry = [
  { id:0, name:"Bob"},
  { id:1, name:"Tim"},
  { id:2, name:"Pete"},
];
```

And I want to update Tim to be "Tim Smith".

```
tableAry[1] = { id:1, name:"Tim Smith"};
```

How do I do this without having to reset the whole array?

```
ractive.set("table",tableAry);
```

Wouldn't that force the whole table to be re-rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target the set to as specific a keypath as possible:

```
// single property
ractive.set("table.1.name", "Tim Smith");

// multiple properties in one go:
ractive.set({
    "table.1.name": "Tim Smith",
    "table.1.age": 12,
});

// you can update the object
var item = ractive.get('table.1');
item.name = 'Tim Smith';
item.age = 22;
ractive.set("table.1", item);
```

That being said, Ractive has some smarts about not re-rendering things of the same value. Though it still has to do more comparisons.